# I don't have a CSS decoder, what software should I download?

Tags: totem

I tried to open movie player with a movie but it gives me crap about a decoding library. Then I learned about the modern CSS scrambling and I couldn't find anything to help.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Installation of **libdvdcss** may be what you need:

1. Install the **libdvdread4** package via command line using [the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

   `sudo apt-get install libdvdread4`
2. Then execute:

   `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`
3. Rebooting may be necessary.

After this, [VLC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/) will automatically use it. Some programs may need recompilation.

Source: [RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs).